# Convert Array of Integers to Set then Find Intersection

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, set

So this is for a project I am working on. Please see this Imgur link to see the instructions.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d64zW.png

[I have this to work too from but it doesn't seem to be helping me much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8f8o.png)

This is a lab I am working on to find the intersection of 2 sets. I have tried everything I can possibly imagine. Here is my code. I believe my main issues are: saving the number of lines below to an integer and converting a string array to a integer array then adding that to a set.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.*;

public class intersectionRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("intersection.dat"));
int numberOfProjects = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); //proven to be =3
int numLinesBelow=0;
for(int i=0; i<numberOfProjects; i++) {
//proven to run 3 times
    Set<Integer> intersection = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    if(in.nextLine().length()==1) {
        numLinesBelow=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(numLinesBelow);
    }
    for(int j =0; j< 0; j++) {
        
    }
}
    
    
    //MAIN ENDS
}
    
    
    
    //CLASS ENDS
}
```

Right now my output is: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:  Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int at intersectionRunner.main(intersectionRunner.java:18)`

This is a disaster, to be honest. I am freaking out because I have tried everything I can think of and it all ends in error. And is due tomorrow

Input file is shown below

```
3
1 2 3 4 5 5
3 4 5 6 7 5
4 5 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
5
10 11 15 61 42 14 112 34
12 13 11 61 42 10 34 12 14 112
10 10 13 11 112 54 61 13 13 34
11 112 15 42 13 34 17 10
71 10 11 112 75 63 15 42 34 56 67
4
1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue please instead of

```
numLinesBelow=in.nextLine();
```

use

```
numLinesBelow=in.nextInt();
```

or just parse your string to int after checking